# Skype shows "Virtual device" for Microphone, speakers and ringing

Tags: sound, skype

I have Ubuntu 14.04.1 and Skype 4.03.0.37. 
my audio devices are working fine but when I make  Skype calls I can't hear the other person neither they can hear me.

when I checked Skype audio settings it showed `virtual device` as the only option for all devices.

I tried a lot of proposed solutions on the web and nothing helped.

what could be the problem and how can I fix it?
I know there is not a lot of details in the question to help, what extra details do  I need to provide ?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

finally solved.
I am running a 64-bit machine and a 32-bit Skype, so I just installed the `libpulse` 32 bit version:

`sudo apt-get install libpulse0:i386`
is all what was needed to solve the problem

Comment: Weird, the default skype package is 32 bit. Is there no 64 bit one?

Comment: I think this fix made all my sound stop working on 15.10.

Answer (score 6):

I had your problem as well and solved it by installing pulseaudio and it's dependencies 
(packages paprefs, pavucontrol, pavumeter are not necessary, at least Skype works without them).
I restarted Skype, and now it lists "PulseAudio Server (local)" for microphone, speaker and ring tone.
Seems like a missing dependency in the skype package.

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem. pulseaudio:i386 was already installed.

Comment: This was also my problem on 16.04

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the reason is that I don't use PulseAudio and "as of version 4.3, the ALSA sound system is no longer supported without PulseAudio" [(source)](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA10964/how-do-i-adjust-the-sound-settings-on-my-computer-and-in-skype-for-linux)

Answer (score -1):

The "solve everything" command from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure made it work on Ubuntu 15.10.

**Warning**: This solution may create problems for users of the other flavors of Ubuntu like Lubuntu.

```
sudo apt-get update;sudo apt-get dist-upgrade; sudo apt-get install pavucontrol linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils lightdm ubuntu-desktop  linux-image-`uname -r` libasound2; sudo apt-get -y --reinstall install linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils lightdm ubuntu-desktop  linux-image-`uname -r` libasound2; killall pulseaudio; rm -r ~/.pulse*; ubuntu-support-status; sudo usermod -aG `cat /etc/group | grep -e '^pulse:' -e '^audio:' -e '^pulse-access:' -e '^pulse-rt:' -e '^video:' | awk -F: '{print $1}' | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's:,$::g'` `whoami`
```

Then reboot.

Comment: @downvoters please explain ;-)

Comment: because in Lubunut, it force the user to download whole gnome and other stuffs and will make the distro unstable

Comment: @Woeitg thanks for explaining. Also consider contacting the people who maintain that Ubuntu help page to have it updated. Cheers!

Comment: well, in that page it is written that this solution will destroy other flavors, however you didn't copy that info! so there is nothing wrong with the solution provided by help.ubuntu.com